Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o117.showString
I am encountering a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$ error when trying to run a PySpark query to show tables from Hive. My environment setup is as follows:
PySpark version: 3.3.4
Hadoop version: 3.3.6
Hive version: 3.1.3
PostgreSQL for Hive Metastore
Here is the snippet of my code:

spark.sql("SHOW DATABASES").show()

spark.sql("USE customer")


this code was worked perfectly, but, i got a problem when execute
tables_df = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES")  # Tampilkan daftar tabel
tables_df.show()  # Tampilkan hasil

with error
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[6], line 2
      1 tables_df = spark.sql("SHOW TABLES")  # Tampilkan daftar tabel
----> 2 tables_df.show()  # Tampilkan hasil

File d:\PySpark\pys390\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\dataframe.py:440, in DataFrame.show(self, n, truncate, vertical)
    406 """Prints the first ``n`` rows to the console.
    407 
    408 :param n: Number of rows to show.
   (...)
    437  name | Bob
    438 """
    439 if isinstance(truncate, bool) and truncate:
--> 440     print(self._jdf.showString(n, 20, vertical))
    441 else:
    442     print(self._jdf.showString(n, int(truncate), vertical))

File d:\PySpark\pys390\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1304, in JavaMember.__call__(self, *args)
   1298 command = proto.CALL_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1299     self.command_header +\
   1300     args_command +\
   1301     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1303 answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1304 return_value = get_return_value(
   1305     answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1307 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1308     temp_arg._detach()

File d:\PySpark\pys390\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\utils.py:128, in capture_sql_exception.<locals>.deco(*a, **kw)
    126 def deco(*a, **kw):
    127     try:
--> 128         return f(*a, **kw)
    129     except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    130         converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)

File d:\PySpark\pys390\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o117.showString.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:229)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:190)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:473)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:459)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3908)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$head$1(Dataset.scala:2903)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$2(Dataset.scala:3898)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution$.withInternalError(QueryExecution.scala:510)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.$anonfun$withAction$1(Dataset.scala:3896)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$6(SQLExecution.scala:109)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:169)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1(SQLExecution.scala:95)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.withActive(SparkSession.scala:779)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:64)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3896)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2903)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:3124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:326)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
    at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
    at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)

I've tried verifying the classpath, ensuring all necessary JARs are available, and checked my Scala version compatibility. The problem persists. Any advice on how to resolve this issue? Thanks in advance for your help!
i don kow anything about java, it makes me frustated. Thanks for your help
